# How do I get Excel to accept 'textjoin' or 'concat' from NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, libreoffice

I can get Excel to take formula from NodeJS. Sums are fine. If Statements are fine. Concatenate works too. Textjoin and Concat do not. Excel does not seem to recognize the coding until the text from it is copied and pasted into a new cell. I was just able to say `{ f: "Sum(:A1:A2") }` and that'd work fine. Is there some notation I need to know about, or a packet I need to download? Concatenate is nice, but it does not cover ranges.

Shortened code:

````
var XLSX = require("xlsx");
var fs = require("fs"); //Helps navigate directory

  function getHeaderRow(sheet) { //Copying specific data from my excel files
      var headers = [];
      var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet["!ref"]);
      let C;
      var R = range.s.r;
  
      /* start in the first row */
      for (C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
        /* walk every column in the range */
        var cell = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: C, r: R })];
        /* find the cell in the first row */
        let hdr = "UNKNOWN " + C; // <-- replace with your desired default
        if (cell && cell.t) hdr = XLSX.utils.format_cell(cell);
        headers.push(hdr);
      }
      return headers;
    }

function readFileToJson(filename, sheet){ 
    var workbook = XLSX.readFile(filename);
    var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheet];
    var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);
    range.s.r = 2; // <-- zero-indexed, so setting to 1 will skip row 0
    worksheet['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
    header = getHeaderRow(worksheet,range);
    range.s.r = 3; var header = getHeaderRow(worksheet,range);
    var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

    var newData = data.map(function(record){ 
        var ConcatColumn = '=CONCAT(AF1:AF5)';
        record.Concats = { f: ConcatColumn};    
    }
    return newData;
}

var targetDir = __dirname + "/Want_Combined";
var files = fs.readdirSync(targetDir); //Can get undwanted files in folder.
var combinedData = [];


files.forEach(function(file){ //For loop
    var FilePath = __dirname + "/Want_Combined/" + file;

    var data = readFileToJson(FilePath, "2"); //Calls function

    combinedData = combinedData.concat(['']).concat(['']).concat(data); //Add a space between entries
    
});
    var newWB = XLSX.utils.book_new(); //New Document
    var newWS = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(combinedData); //New Sheet, data is on it. Pasted at A3.
    
    
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(newWB,newWS,"Category 2"); //Combining all
    

    XLSX.writeFile(newWB,"Results/GData.xlsx"); //Saving file
    console.log("Done!");```
````

Comment: ...what does Excel have to do with NodeJS?

Comment: I'm using NodeJs to write Excel files. I'm able to put some formulas into some cells, but other formula don't seem to work. I'm hoping there is a workaround, or a notation change needed on my part.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Added a shortened form of it. I throw formula into the Concat column. It shows up in the written Excel file, but does not execute the formula. It'll execute Sum Formulas passed in the same manner, and IF statements. Just not Concat and Textjoin for some reason. Shortened it because it would be difficult to parse if I gave the full coding. Quite a trainwreck, but it works. Except this part.

Comment: Your `data.map` code is incorrect (assuming that's `Array.prototype.map`).

Comment: I mean, it works just fine. I'll want to later do away with the map function altogether and do a for loop to save memory. The program runs as intended. The text I'm sending goes to Excel. Excel just doesn't understand that it's a function I'm sending. I tried using v: instead, which is cell value. Same thing, the text is correct in Excel. I can see it in the Cell, it just isn't acting like a cell function. If I swap the text in my coding with other Excel functions like 'SUM' and others, they work just fine in Excel. It recognizes those functions. Excel seems to recognize some and not others.

Comment: Have you extracted the inner OOXML from your `.xlsx` and compared it to a Workbook created in Excel using the same formula functions?

Comment: You'll have to explain that, I'm not sure what you're referring to. If that helps it talk better with Excel, I'll do it. Excel is clearly receiving the right text, just not doing anything with it.

Comment: 1. Create a new workbook in Excel, and use `TEXTJOIN` and/or `CONCAT` in some cells and save it to a new file: `knowngood.xslx`. 2. Use a tool like 7Zip to extract the contents of the `.xlsx` file (it's just a `.zip` file in disguise). 3. Get one of the `.xlsx` files generated by your NodeJS code and do the same thing: extract its contents. 4. Browse the extracted files for the `.xml` files containing the cell data. 5. Compare the XML from `knowngood.xlsx` with the XML from your NodeJS-generaated file. 6. Spot the difference.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow, it's 2:30 AM. If you've a tutorial handy, would greatly appreciate it. If the process is fairly straight forward, then I shouldn't struggle to much to compare the 2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't, sorry.

Comment: So what was the problem in the end?

Comment: Invisible letters needed to be added to the front of those specific formulas. _xlfn.